# Como pegar um valor de um input diferenciado usando BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

To fazendo um programinha pra aprender a usar o BeautifulSoup e estou fazendo um negociador de moedas que converte o valor da moeda X para a moeda Y, meu programa inicialmente pega do site do iban todas os códigos das moedas existentes e depois uso o site transferwise pra converter o valor, atualmente eu pego o valor que 1 moeda vale na outra moeda e passo pro programa e faço a conversão lá, mas na propria pagina ele já converte o valor que eu passar, no caso se eu passo 50 BRL ele já me dá o valor convertido em USD que é 9.44645 por exemplo, só que que esse valor em USD eu não estou conseguindo pegar pra passar pro meu programa, pelo o que eu entendi ele é um input que fica atualizando em tempo real.

O site que eu converto é https://transferwise.com/gb/currency-converter/brl-to-usd-rate?amount=33.6 e div que ta o valor que eu quero pegar é :

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
<input type="text" class="js-TargetAmount form-control cc-calculator__input" id="cc-amount-to" data-element="target" data-type="amount" value="" data-hj-whitelist="">
</div>
```

Negocio é, como podem ver o value ta "", não salva o valor ai, ai não sei pegar o valor que aparece na pagina.
O meu programa ta aqui https://repl.it/@SrTony/Teste-web-scraping se quiserem olhar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que seja um site dinâmico, sendo assim só o BeautifulSoup não conseguiria dar conta de pegar alguns elementos. Tenta usar a lib selenium `pip3 install selenium` .
Ela consegue lidar com sites dinâmicos

Comment: Obrigado, vou ver como funciona esse lib e fazer os testes aqui. Valeu.